# Fetch Only PHP Response using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to transfer data using AJAX. I've got two files, one has PHP, HTML and another one has JS Code:

**test.php:**

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["txtField"])){
      echo "OK";
    }else{
      echo "NOT OK";
    }
  }

 ?>



<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Ground</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtField" />
    <input type="button" id="sendInput" value="Send" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js:**

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $("#sendInput").on("click", sendInput);
});

function sendInput(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {txtField: $("#txtField").val()}
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

And everything works fine till i recieve response from PHP to JS. In console.log data shown also includes HTML code along with PHP response "OK". But I want just the PHP response, nothing else. I know i can fetch the whole data and remove everything under HTML tags or create a separate file for PHP, but is there anyway which directly returns just the response from PHP without creating separate PHP file.

Comment: You need to create a separate file, or split your logic via conditions so that only the values you require are returned in the AJAX request. The former would be better.

Comment: Add `exit;` after the echo of ok?

Comment: Separate your PHP and HTML code to different file.

Comment: @Qirel that would then break anywhere this page is used from a standard (ie non-AJAX) request.

Comment: RoryMcCrossan I think @Qirel 's solution will work, by putting the code inside a function. I'll give it a try. And let you know.

Comment: Assuming it's loaded from multiple sites, you are indeed correct (If I overlooked the specification by OP, I'm sorry).  It's possible to send another post-item with that Ajax though, and check for that, exit if it's set.

Comment: @Qirel Your Solution Works perfectly along with my add-on. The only thing need to be kept in mind is that. Function is called above HTML code. Thank You for the Solution. It really helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exit()` function to get the correct return :

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST["txtField"])) {
      echo "OK";
      exit();
    } else {
      echo "NOT OK";
    }
  }
```

When you send an Ajax call, the server return all the printed value on your file. So the HTML is printed too.
Like that, you print only 'OK' because `exit()` stops the execution file, and only OK is printed.

Note, it's more appropriate to use a separate PHP file and HTML file, when you use AJAX.

Comment: But if i create a function and put above code inside it. Then wouldn't it be Ok?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your PHP file like this:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["txtField"])){
      echo "OK";
    }else{
      echo "NOT OK";
    }
  }

  // This is what i have added.
  if(isset($_GET["fromJS"]))
    die();
  // Till here, so if this GET param is set noting will come up further this.
 ?>



<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Ground</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtField" />
    <input type="button" id="sendInput" value="Send" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And make your AJAX call to `test.php?fromJS=true`

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $("#sendInput").on("click", sendInput);
});

function sendInput(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php?fromJS=true",
    method: "POST",
    data: {txtField: $("#txtField").val()}
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: @madalinivascu where?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 php file one for the ajax and one for the page that sends the ajax, if you want to stick with one php page try this code:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["txtField"])){
      echo "OK";
    }else{
      echo "NOT OK";
    }
  } else {

 ?>



<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Ground</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtField" />
    <input type="button" id="sendInput" value="Send" />
  </body>
</html>

<?php }?>
```